# MFC: Best way to get text from a CRichEdit?

Tags: c++, mfc, crichedit

I've got a CRichEdit that I need to get the text from. What is the best way to do that? [GETTEXTEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787913(v=VS.85).aspx)? [StreamOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0k0ywek(v=VS.80).aspx)? If I go the StreamOut approach, what would my callback look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's inherited from CWnd so you should just be able to use GetWindowText().

```
CString returnText;
yourRichEdit.GetWindowText(returnText);
```